# How to remove the top left corner buttons of the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

By default there are the two buttons **plan** and **satellite** at the top left corner of the map :

[image]

Here is code :

```
<script>
  map = null;
  poly = null;
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                                              zoom: 7,
                                                              center: {lat: -18.92379, lng: 47.542537},
                                                              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                                            }
                               );
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                  strokeColor: '#000000',
                                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                  strokeWeight: 3
                                });
  poly.setMap(map);
  document.getElementById('organisation').addEventListener('change', function() {
    getFlotteByOrganisation(document.getElementById('organisation').value);
  });
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCSJrLcMUVltUHcVjtC8ZotBshfiue8J68&callback=initMap"></script>
```

How to remove these two buttons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to disable the default user interface:

```
disableDefaultUI: true
```

Add back in the street view control and the zoom control (if you want them):

```
streetViewControl: true, // add back streetView control
zoomControl: true, // add back the zoom control
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  map = null;
  poly = null;

  function initMap() {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {
        lat: -18.92379,
        lng: 47.542537
      },
      disableDefaultUI: true, // disable the default controls
      streetViewControl: true, // add back streetView control
      zoomControl: true, // add back the zoom control
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCSJrLcMUVltUHcVjtC8ZotBshfiue8J68&callback=initMap"></script>
```